# Is there a shortcut for switching between preview modes in Fireworks CS6?

Tags: cs6, adobe-fireworks, shortcuts

I switch between the original, 2-up and 4-up modes frequently, yet can't find a keyboard shortcut for it anywhere.

What is the keyboard shortcut for changing the preview mode?

If there isn't one, is there any way for me to create the keyboard shortcut myself?

Answer (score 1):

After going to `Fireworks -> Keyboard Shorcuts..`:

[image]

I found that there is not a shortcut or a way to create a shortcut for `Original`, `Preview`, `2-up` or `4-up`.

The documentation [Select and customize keyboard shortcuts](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/fireworks/cs/using/WS4c25cfbb1410b0021e63e3d1152b00d9a7-7ff8.html) did not render any help either.